# Need to select all rows from 2 tables with a common date field

Tags: mysql, sql

So, I have found myself in the unenviable position of having to play DBA (I'm a sysadmin, normally), and the issue I have is this:

I have two tables, one for people to record when they arrive on site, and another table for when they leave.

Ideally, the data between the two tables should just match, and I should be able to use an inner JOIN on them to get the view I want. But what we have been seeing is that people are not checking in and out like they should. So, this means I can have some people in the checkin table that won't be in the checkout table, and vice versa.

I've tried a Left JOIN between the two tables, but that still duplicates some of the rows of the checkin table in the output...

```
SELECT a.name,a.timein,a.signature,b.timeout,b.signature 
FROM check_in a
LEFT JOIN check_out b ON a.datein = b.dateout
WHERE a.datein = '2019-01-28';
```

What I would like is one query that will let me get all the rows from the checkin table for today's date, and also pull all the rows from teh checkout table in the same result set for today's date.

Is there any way for that to be done, or am I just going to have to use two queries until I can get this data stored in one table?

Comment: Could you provide sample data, and your expected output for that data?

Comment: Does `check_out` have `name` too (or, better, some person ID)? Would it work to do a full outer join on `name` and `datein`/`dateout`?  (And then have the `WHERE` clause check both dates...)

Comment: Yes, check_out has the person's name as well... but the issue is that if I try and match the names, I will miss some data, because people aren't checking in, but they are checking out, or they are checking in, and aren't checking out. That's why I'm trying to get all rows from both tables for the same day...

Comment: What database engine? Some DBs allow a FULL JOIN type join that might do what you need, and some don't.

Comment: Also, I was trying to use the FULL JOIN, but in MySQL Workbench, it kept giving me a syntax error. I had thought that would be the best way to do it, but I must be missing something to run it in the Workbench.

Comment: So, I googled for a full join in MySQL, and found that it doesn't support that function, but you can emulate it using UNION... I'm going to go try that and see if it gives me what I am looking for.

Comment: Oh. MySql. Condolences.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a full outer join, but you need to join on the common identifier between the tables. At the moment you're joining on date, which would join all the rows in check_in for the date, with all the rows from check_out for the date (i.e., if you had 5 people checkin and check out on the example day, you'd get 25 rows returned). So assuming `name` is the identifier, you'd do something like:

```
SELECT a.name,a.timein,a.signature,b.timeout,b.signature, b.name 
FROM check_in a
FULL OUTER JOIN check_out b ON a.name = b.name
    and a.datein = b.dateout
WHERE a.datein = '2019-01-28' 
OR b.dateout = '2019-01-28';
```

I've included `b.name` in the result because if someone has checked out, but not in then you wouldn't get a value for `a.name`.

Another option might be to do a union, so go with something like:

```
SELECT a.name,a.timein,a.signature,b.timeout,b.signature
FROM check_in a
LEFT OUTER JOIN check_out b ON a.name = b.name
    and a.datein = b.dateout
WHERE a.datein = '2019-01-28' 
UNION
SELECT co.name, '', '', co.timeout, co.signature
FROM check_out co
where not exists (SELECT 1 
    FROM check_in ci
    WHERE ci.name = co.name 
    AND ci.datein = co.dateout)
AND co.dateout = '2019-01-28'
```

So the top half of the query will return matches and those with a check in and checkout, along with those with a checkin but not a check out, and the bottom half selects those with a check out but not a matching check in, however it returns the check_out name in the first column, so column 1 will always have the name.

Then you can take it from there how fancy you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the rows where the check in date matches the checkout date *or* there’s no check in date *or* there’s no check out date, so I would write the query like:

```
SELECT a.name, a.timein, a.signature, b.timeout, b.signature
FROM check_in a, check_out b,
WHERE a.user = b.user
AND a.datein = ‘2019-01-28’
AND (a.datein = b.dateout OR a.datein IS NULL OR b.dateout IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

A full outer join will get rows from both `check_in` and `check_out`, as long as at least one of the dates matches the one you're looking for.  A simple `OR` in the `WHERE` clause should be sufficient to get all the records you want.

```
SELECT a.name, a.timein, a.signature, b.timeout, b.signature 
FROM check_in a
FULL OUTER JOIN check_out b
ON a.datein = b.dateout AND a.name = b.name
WHERE a.datein = '2019-01-28' OR b.dateout = '2019-01-28';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all`:

```
select c.*
from ((select ci.name, ci.timein, ci.signature as in_signature,
              null as timeout, null as out_signature
       from check_in ci
       where ci.check_in = '2019-01-28'
      ) union all
      (select co.name, null, null,
              co.timeout, co.signature as out_signature
       from check_out co
       where ci.check_in = '2019-01-28'
      )
     ) c;
```

I strongly discourage you from using `join` for bringing the data together because that could multiple the number of rows.  You'll want to get a better idea of what is in the data without multiplying the rows from either table.